# Direct Message other people on ROS Answers?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if the administrators could permit direct messages to people on ROS answers (based on people accepting requests or some other form of privacy protection of course). Because some times, you are stuck at a single point and it makes sense to directly interact with someone who has solved the problem before without having to use answers and comments which are way less efficient and might be spam-like to others.

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182944/direct-message-other-people-on-ros-answers?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please just use the @ notation to notify the other user. It is not helpful for the rest of the community if you solve the problems offline. If you need to have a series of comments to make progress it's not considered spam. If you want completely interactive support you can meet them on IRC or any other communication channel you would like if they're willing to do that. It is usually useful to keep your conversation on the question though so that others who might have knowledge in the area can jump in after you have added more debugging information.

So as long as you're on topic and focused on answering the specific question don't feel bad about having a long comment stream. Once you solve the problem it would be helpful to write up an answer as a summary.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know this is not possible intentionally. Answers and the way towards those should be documented for others that run into the same problem. Also people might get annoyed with direct help requests that would take extra time. A simple way might be to ask in a comment.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1